# Spark is not loading all multiline json objects in a single file even with multiline option set to true

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My json file looks like below, it has got two multiline json objects (in a single file)

```
{
    "name":"John Doe",
    "id":"123456"
}
{
    "name":"Jane Doe",
    "id":"456789"
}
```

So when i load multiline  json dataframe it should load two json instead it is loading first json object only. How can i load all the multiline json  objects in a single file?

```
val rawData = spark.read.option("multiline", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").format("json").load("/tmp/search/baggage/test/1")
scala> rawData.show
+------+--------+
|    id|    name|
+------+--------+
|123456|John Doe|
+------+--------+

scala> rawData.count
res20: Long = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input Json is not a valid json, valid JSON will look like below:

```
[{
    "name":"John Doe",
    "id":"123456"
},
{
    "name":"Jane Doe",
    "id":"456789"
}]
```

Creating DataFrame from above json will create a right dataframe.

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(j, ["id", "name"])
>>> df.show()
+------+--------+
|    id|    name|
+------+--------+
|123456|John Doe|
|456789|Jane Doe|
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have a related question say if my json file has got data in single lines then it will be loaded properly.```{"name":"John Doe","id":"123456"} \n  {"name":"Jane Doe","id":"456789"}```. I assume this will also be invalid json?

Comment: Yes, the json u have specified will also be invalid. You can use jsonlint.com to validate any json.

Answer (score 3):

Your input JSON is not valid, it misses brackets as you have multiples objects. You can check this using any json validator tool. That's why `multiLine` option won't work in this case.

That said, I think you want to use [JsonLines](http://jsonlines.org/) format where each line represents a JSON object.

```json
{"name":"John Doe","id":"123456"}
{"name":"Jane Doe","id":"456789"}
```

Spark can read this JSON without setting `multiline` option:

```scala
val df = spark.read.json("file:///your/json/file.json")
df.show()
```

Output :

```
+------+--------+
|    id|    name|
+------+--------+
|123456|John Doe|
|456789|Jane Doe|
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you @blackbishop: Yes this works. Unfortunately i am at the consumer side i cant alter the data, seems like, i really dont have much options! My question is more like if this is valid and works perfectly why can't multi object multilne json file cant work with mutliline option set to true?

Comment: The specifications for `JsonLines` are  : (1) each line is a valid JSON object. (2) lines are separated by `\n`. If it does not respect these specifications so it's not valid `JsonLines` and as the objects are not in an array so it's not valid JSON also.